# How to write a query to delete everything except maximum value grouped by an ID?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to write a query to delete duplicate records based on a ID and a value. There are multiple rows with the same ID. Condition to get the result are (and the queries I have written as per my understanding),

1. Look for maximum value available for the ID column in Value column (`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE IN (SELECT MAX(VALUE) FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID`)

Example:

Table data:

ID - Value

a - 1

a - 2

a - 3

b - 2

c - 3

Output:

ID - Value

a - 3

b - 2

c - 3

2. Ignore the results from point 1 in the table (`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NOT EXISTS ((SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE IN (SELECT MAX(VALUE) FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID)`)

Edit: I wrote a query that finally outputs the required result for point 2

```
SELECT t1.* FROM TABLE t1 
  LEFT JOIN
  ( 
    SELECT 1 AS aux, * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE
    WHERE VALUE IN 
    (SELECT MAX(VALUE) FROM TABLE group by ID))
  ) t2
  ON 
  t2.ID= t1.ID
  and 
  t2.VALUE= t1.VALUE
  WHERE t2.aux IS NULL
```

Example:

Table data:

ID - Value

a - 1

a - 2

a - 3

b - 2

c - 3

Output:

ID - Value

a - 1

a - 2

3. Use the query of point 2 to delete rows from table (`DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE (ID,VALUE) IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NOT EXISTS ((SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE IN (SELECT MAX(VALUE) FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID))`)

Example:

Table data:

ID - Value

a - 1

a - 2

a - 3

b - 2

c - 3

Table data:

ID - Value

a - 3

b - 2

c - 3

Point 2 does not work, it is giving no results. When the checked the total row of output of the query from point 2 and total row of the table, there is a difference.

Since point 2 does not work, point 3 fails as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the output in your point 3 the desired and final one?

Comment: Yes. @AlexandreMoraes.

Comment: I have added a query that outputs the desired result of point 2 @AlexandreMoraes

Comment: For point 1 I am getting a different output. However, if you desire the last output as the final one, you can simply use something like: SELECT id, MAX(Value) as max_val from ` your_table ` group by id order by id; Wouldn't this work for you?

Comment: Yes, this works! I have to mention the column names in select statement. There is simply too many off them, so does this query work too? : select a.* from 
TABLE a
left join
(SELECT ID, MAX(VALUE) as max_val from TABLE group by ID) b
ON  a.ID= b.ID
and a.VALUE= b.max_val
 (Edit: Just checked. This query does not work). Also Is it better to do DELETE statement or OVERWRITE using the query you've mentioned? @AlexandreMoraes

Comment: Could you please elaborate more when you say there are too many of the columns for you to select? I can help you write a script that suits you. Why do you want to use DELETE or OVERWRITE with the query I wrote ? What do you want to accomplish with that?

Comment: Also, the query provided in the comment section you just select columns from one table, therefore the output would be equal to the input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206860/discussion-between-alexandre-moraes-and-jeeva-bharathi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our discussion, I understand that you aimed to select many rows of data which respects the filter ***id*** and ***max(value)***. Therefore, I can suggest you the following script:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT a.*
FROM
  `test-proj-261014.sample.id_value` a
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    MAX(value) AS max_val
  FROM
    `test-proj-261014.sample.id_value`
  GROUP BY
    id
  ORDER BY
    id) b
ON
  a.id = b.id
  AND a.value = b.max_val
WHERE
  a.value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  id;
```

Not that I use [SELECT DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax), which will not select duplicated data. In addition, due to the possibility of the existence of null values, I added the consition***WHERE a.value IS NOT NULL***, which will not select the rows that do not respect the condition.

The above query should solve the problem, however if you find any discrepancy with the expected amount of rows, I encourage you explore your data set and detect the reason why there are extra or less rows. You can use different types of joins to do so, one example would be the following query:

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM
  `test-proj-261014.sample.id_value` a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    MAX(value) AS max_val
  FROM
    `test-proj-261014.sample.id_value`
  GROUP BY
    id
  ORDER BY
    id) b
ON
  a.id = b.id
  AND a.value = b.max_val
WHERE
  b.max_val IS NULL
ORDER BY
  id;
```

This query retrieves all the values which are not present in the final output generated by the first query. This would help you understand better the data you are dealing with.

I hope it helps.